# vuetify: v-chip v-model using dynamic lists

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a vuetify component to display a list of tags.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-chip 
            v-for="tag in tags" 
            :key="tag.id" 
            v-model="???"
            @input="onClose(tag)"
            close
        >
            {{tag.name}}
        </v-chip>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'TagIndex',
        props: ['tags'],

        methods: {
            onClose(tag){
                console.log('close tag')
            }
        }
    }    
</script>
```

The vuetify documentation says:

> Closable chips can be controlled with a v-model.

I do not understand what kind of object I need to specify as a model for each tag if the list of tags is dynamic.

I tried to create an array based on a list of tags:

```
data(){
  return {
    clonedTags: this.tags.map((t) => {return true})
  }
}
```

But has failed

Comment: Looks like tags should be an array and the v-model should be v-model="tag". Does that work for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `v-model` in this component is bound to the open/closed state of the tag, so it should just be a Boolean value. [Here's an example fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/1zc0qaj6/1/)

---

In your case, if you gave each object in the `tags` array an `isOpen` property, then you could use it like so:

```
<v-chip 
  v-for="tag in tags" 
  :key="tag.id" 
  v-model="tag.isOpen"
  @input="onClose(tag)"
  close
>
  {{tag.name}}
</v-chip>
```

Then, whenever the value of `tag.isOpen` changes, that change will be reflected in the open/closed state of the component, and vice-versa.

[Here's an example fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/1zc0qaj6/3/)

Comment: Yes, thank you, it almost works. The only thing that does not work is hiding the tag. If I press "close", the value of tag.isOpen becomes false, but the tag itself does not disappear

Comment: Edited to include a fiddle example using `tag.isOpen`. Check to see how your code differs from that

Comment: Yes, our code is the same. The only difference is that I have tags not in data, but in props

Comment: Yes, I found a mistake. The problem was that initially in the tag there was no isOpen property, and I added it when passing the list to the child component
```<tags-view :tags="note.tags.map((t) => {t.isOpen = true; return t})" ></tags-view>```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you @thanksd